# Best options from fix width to responsive frameworks

Tags: css, responsive-design, themes

Currently I am developing website themes with fixed width so please give me a suggestion which framework I should adopt is there any other way to do thing this way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/), it's used by a lot of developers and it's documentation is really helpful.

To learn responsive design better and fast you should:

1. Understand the use of media queries, [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) article will let you
   know about the standards breakpoints for them.
2. You can use LESS or SASS for creating a custom Bootstrap grid
   that suits your project.

Comment: can you please let me know why LESS or SASS i need to use?

Comment: +1 for the best solution.

Comment: @SohailQureshi These CSS preprocessors make your code more efficient, you will write less CSS code, and it will improve your workflow. Check out this beginners guide to LESS: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/less-basic/

Comment: if i use bootstrap for responsive theme development then i also used media queries or javascript will manage it please reply me.

Comment: @SohailQureshi you don't have to use Javascript, with the help of media queries you will be able to make anything you want. I suggest you to check out: Responsive Web Design for Beginners - Tuts+, a very useful resource.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above, frameworks such as Bootstrap really speed up the development time of a website and make adding responsive layouts easier due to the grid system they use. For extra information using bootstrap go to http://www.sitepoint.com/responsive-web-design-tips-bootstrap-css/. They provide some tips on responsive design.

Answer (score 1):

For responsive website designing, you have to understand the css media queries. Though,it will get your job done, but designing through media queries seems like taking lots of efforts, specially when must faster and less time consuming alternatives are available.
I suggest you to go through twiiter bootstrap framework. Responsive website designing is much easier with it. You have to just include a couple of javascript files and apply some predefined classes(as per your need), and you are done.
There are two very good tutorials, i would like to mention. Just go through with them for a clear crisp understanding of bootstrap simplicity in responsive design. They have pretty good examples too. Just try altering your browser width to get a better understanding.

Bootstrap:

[Link 1](http://scotch.io/bar-talk/understanding-the-bootstrap-3-grid-system)

[Link 2](http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-grid-introduction)

Comment: if i use bootstrap for responsive theme development then i also used media queries or javascript will manage it please reply me.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with using Boostrap 3 from personal experience. 
Also instead of setting actual widths setting percentages instead makes it responsive as it goes to the size of whatever screen size you are using, as an example you can use this [link](http://demosthenes.info/blog/586/CSS-Fluid-Image-Techniques-for-Responsive-Site-Design).

Also, check out collapsing navbars for a responsive navigation to be collapsed on smaller devices, here is a link that will help you out: [NAV](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).